# Using PHP for cross-domain post data

Tags: php, redirect, post, header

Using PHP, is it possible to send post data to another domain without using a form?

```
header('location:https://domain.com/webservice/?data=My Data');
```

We can't use the solution above because the GET data is stored in the persons browser history and in some of our server logs (not ideal).

```
curl_init();
```

We can't use this solution because the `/webservice/` uses a `header('location:')` to redirect the user to a final landing page and `curl_init()` captures the data instead of responding to it -- our goal is to have the user change domains along with the post data. The `/webservice/` also creates a new session with the user which is why they need to be at that physical location with the post data.

Anyone have an outside-the-box idea?

Comment: Are the two domains on the same server/hosting account?

Comment: No, there are a number of satellite servers that run on separate domains that all need to access one central domain. It's all part of the same system but the infrastructure is very segmented.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a POST request from your PHP program (see the cURL library) but you can't redirect the browser in such a way that it will make a POST request.

The only way to do that is to generate an HTML document with a form and POST that (which can be done using JS).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, provided both domains can share the same database.

Steps:

1. Generate a value to uniquely identify this session. Better use some simple encoding.
2. Write the data to a table in the database. If not individual fields, even an xml structure in a BLOB field would do, but that's extra work.
3. pass the identifier using a query string to the second domain and get the data from the DB

Additionally you can have a status field to time-out the data and delete the record if it's not read within a certain time period.

Well, this is only an idea but I think it's a workable one that hides your data to some extent compared to sending it all in the query string.

Comment: This idea may be in the right direction but it still relies on using a query string to pass data (insecure). The environment where this works is very public and we're worried about anything that could be stored in the browser history (even if the data is only responsive for a few seconds). Theoretically, it would be possible to breach the data using the identifier you point out in step 3.

Comment: Are you sure it's incecure? I'm guessing at most the data will last for 15 seconds in the table. And how long will you take to figure out a key like **fslkj4390-8f** ? Yes, query strings can be dangerous for 'data' but I don't think this method is bad.

Comment: A packet sniffer with an automated script that detected the outbound identifier and relayed it to the destination server could breach this in 1-2 seconds -- potentially faster than the legitimate user.

If the request generated a SALT which generated the key and the SALT were passed back to the user through curl_init() we could then use that to generate an identifier that could only be accessed one time... (maybe this is what you meant)

If the identifier were only "alive" for 10 seconds, and cleared itself after one access would this be insecure? Does anyone else have feedback on this?

Comment: By the way, the request is being made through SSL as well so it isn't really that easy to sniff but this is in a university environment where some rather intelligent kids tend to do a "lot" of experimenting.

Comment: Oh, so you've gone that far :)
 If you're that much afraid and your network where the site is used is that bad, I think the first step is to get a secure socket encrption.